# How to create a map from a RDD[String] using scala?

Tags: scala

My file is,

```
sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no
overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,TRUE,no
overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes
```

Here there are 7 rows & 5 columns(0,1,2,3,4)

I want the output as,

```
Map(0 -> Set("sunny","overcast","rainy"))
Map(1 -> Set("hot","mild","cool"))
Map(2 -> Set("high","normal"))
Map(3 -> Set("false","true"))
Map(4 -> Set("yes","no"))
```

The output must be the type of [Map[Int,Set[String]]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Rewritten to present the map-reduce version first, as it's more suited to Spark

Since this is Spark, we're probably interested in parallelism/distribution. So we need to take care to enable that.

Splitting each string into words can be done in partitions. Getting the set of values used in each column is a bit more tricky - the naive approach of initialising a set then adding every value from every row is inherently serial/local, since there's only one set (per column) we're adding the value from each row to.

However, if we have the set for some part of the rows and the set for the rest, the answer is just the union of these sets. This suggests a reduce operation where we merge sets for some subset of the rows, then merge those and so on until we have a single set.

So, the algorithm:

- Split each row into an array of strings, then change this into an
  array of sets of the single string value for each column - this can
  all be done with one map, and distributed.
- Now reduce this using an
  operation that merges the set for each column in turn. This also can
  be distributed
- turn the single row that results into a Map

It's no coincidence that we do a map, then a reduce, which should remind you of something :)

Here's a one-liner that produces the single row:

```
val data = List(
"sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no",
"sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no",
"overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes",
"rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes",
"rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes",
"rainy,cool,normal,TRUE,no",
"overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes") 

val row = data.map(_.split("\\W+").map(s=>Set(s)))
              .reduce{(a, b) => (a zip b).map{case (l, r) => l ++ r}}
```

Converting it to a Map as the question asks:

```
val theMap = row.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
```

- Zip the list with the index, since that's what we need as the key of
  the map.
- The elements of each tuple are unfortunately in the wrong
  order for .toMap, so swap them.
- Then we have a list of (key, value)
  pairs which .toMap will turn into the desired result.

These don't need to change AT ALL to work with Spark. We just need to use a RDD, instead of the List. Let's convert data into an RDD just to demo this:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-scratch").setMaster("local")
val sc= new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(data)

val row = rdd.map(_.split("\\W+").map(s=>Set(s)))
             .reduce{(a, b) => (a zip b).map{case (l, r) => l ++ r}}
```

(This can be converted into a Map as before)

An earlier oneliner works neatly (transpose is exactly what's needed here) but is very difficult to distribute (transpose inherently needs to visit every row)

```
data.map(_.split("\\W+")).transpose.map(_.toSet)
```

(Omitting the conversion to Map for clarity)

- Split each string into words.
- Transpose the result, so we have a list that has a list of the first words, then a list of the second words, etc.
- Convert each of those to a set.

Comment: nice one. Just wanted to say that, in the specific case, `split(',')` would work the same

Comment: Indeed it would. But the `split` is probably the least interesting bit of this :)

Comment: Yup, just a minor note in fact.

Comment: @Paul But 1 problem, here the " val rdd " is List(...) . I want the " val rdd " as RDD[String] not List[String]. If we change the List to RDD, WE CAN'T APPLY TRANSPOSE, SWAP etc....., Any solution?????

Comment: Sorry, I'm not experienced with RDD. If it doesn't support `transpose` then another solution may be best (`swap` however is about the elements  in the RDD, and not the RDD itself so that should be usable since RDD does support `map`?). Or write your own `transpose` (it's five `map` operations, one for each index, which should paralleize nicely) - but in that case you could add things to the set in each `map` as you go, saving some time.

Comment: Updated with another version using that approach

Comment: @Paul,Thanks for ur reply. But In scala, RDD plays an important role. If we create all things as RDD, for example: RDD[String], RDD[Int], RDD[List[]] etc.... We can run our scala code even for a terabyte data. But If we use Array,List etc...It need some for storing, so for a large data,it won't work.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem in practice. The split list can be an RDD[List[String]) (will be anyway, if you the original list is an RDD). You can change findSets to take an RDD[List[String]. And the return value from that is a small Array  (5 elements) so the storage of that isn't a problem

Comment: @Paul, There is one error in last line , ie. In sc.makeRDD(findSets(myRdd.map(_.split("\\W+"))).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap) . Error is Cannot resolve symbol

Comment: What is the symbol it can't resolve? (You may need to sort this one out yourself, as I can't get Eclipse to compile any of my Spark tests. I will try again later, but it's working hours for me now)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this do the trick:

```
    val a = Array(
      "sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no",
      "sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no",
      "overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes",
      "rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes",
      "rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes",
      "rainy,cool,normal,TRUE,no",
      "overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes")

    val b  = new Array[Map[String, Set[String]]](5)

    for (i <- 0 to 4)
      b(i) = Map(i.toString -> (Set() ++ (for (s <- a) yield s.split(",")(i))) )

    println(b.mkString("\n"))
```